# Javascript Array.sort behavior with mixed value types?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, types

Is there a defined behavior for `Array.sort` in javascript for arrays with mixed types?  One thing that is seemingly strange to me is the following (tested in chrome):

```
'' > -1          // returns true
'' < -1          // returns false
[-1,''].sort()   // returns ['', -1]
```

Now, if `-1` is less than `''`, then it seems like `.sort` would put -1 *earlier* in the sorted array, rather than later.

Other experiments reveal that `'pickles'` is  neither greater than, less than nor equal to `-1`, but `.sort` will put `'pickles'` after any `int`s, no matter how large.  Also, `null` gets put last despite being "small" according to the `<,>` operators, and `undefined` gets put last despite being neither greater, less or equal to numbers.

Is the behavior of `Array.sort` well-defined for mixed-type arrays, and if so, what is the expected behavior here?

Comment: The sort doesn't do `'' > -1` it's more like `'' > '-1'` since it will compare as strings

Comment: @VLAZ "compare as strings" ahhhhh, this is right in the docs, I see now.

Comment: Per MDN's [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) documentation: "The default sort order is ascending, built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values."